# Workflow Dependency Property

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, dependency-properties

I have a `Person` class with a name property.

I have a custom activity that have this Person object as a dependency property.

Now when I drop this custom activity into the workflow designer. I can see the Person in the property grid.

From the designer I'd like to be able to specify the name of the person.

Is this possible? Or the only way is to really create a Name property in my Custom activity.

Comment: Try re-reading and then clarifying this question, currently I can't make out what it is you are asking?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I've edited, hope it's more clear

Answer (score 0):

Since this is unanswered for ages now I'll add an answer because it might help someone.

From what I understand you have an object x stored in a property of control and you'd like to show a property of the object x.
An example could be a combobox which contains an array of person. But you don't want person to show in the combobox. You might want to show their names.

You can achieve that by setting `DisplayMemberBinding="name"`.